# Escaping percentage character in Sass (SCSS)

Tags: css, variables, sass, escaping, semantics

I have a question surrounding semantics.

I am working with a long list of variables in Sass (it's a large number of color swatches and corresponding tints). These colors have to be precise and so `lighten()` and `darken()` functions don't suit in this scenario.

The variables I'm currently declaring read like the following:

`$black-13-percent-tint`, `$black-21-percent-tint`, etc.

I stumbled across [this article](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class), got excited, and slightly misinterpreted what the article was saying. I then began trying to declare Sass variables like the following:

`$black-13\%-tint`, `$black-21\%-tint`, etc.

After realizing my error (mixing up class names and Sass variables) I started to wonder if it was possible to escape the `%` symbol in a Sass variable?

Essentially  I would like to write Sass like the following example and I am wanting to know if it is possible to achieve this?

`.black-13\%-tint-swatch {
  background: $black-13\%-tint;
}`

Comment: Why not use this mixin to do the job for you?

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/tint-shade-functions/

Comment: Thank you @ShannonYoung I did come across this after my question. Technically this mixin could solve my problem in a different way. But I still would like to know if their is a way to use the percentage character when declaring a Sass variable.

Answer (score 36):

You can use `#{'%'}`, that worked for me :)

Comment: This worked for me for the period (.) for opacity too.

opacity: #{'.'} + #{$opacity};